# Trying to select onward date from RedBus.com

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm new to selenium. I'm trying to select Onward date from RedBus.com, Can someone help me on this. Below is the code which I have tried.

```
public class RedBusSearch extends RedBusLibraries {

 public RedBus red = null;
 public WebDriver driver = null;

 @Test public void travel() {

 logger = extent.createTest("SpiceJet flight bookin");

  red = new RedBus(driver); 

  delay(3000); 

 input(red.getSource(), "Hyderabad", "source"); 

  input(red.getDestination(), "Bangalore", "Destination"); 

   click(red.getOnwardDate(), "onwards date"); 

  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='rb-calendar_onward_cal']")); 

  List<WebElement> month = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='rb-calendar']/table/tbody/tr/td")); 

 System.out.println(month.size());

for (WebElement ele : month)
{

 if (ele.getText().equals("15")) 

    ele.findElement(By.linkText("15")).click();

  break;

     }
  }
}
```

,,,

Answer (score 0):

You have to click on the next month button until you reach your desired month in year. Then select the date. Here is the logic to select `15 May 2019`

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[for='onward_cal']")).click();
    //select month
    while(!driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#rb-calendar_onward_cal .monthTitle")).getText().equals("May 2019")) {
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".rb-calendar#rb-calendar_onward_cal .next button")).click();
        System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#rb-calendar_onward_cal .monthTitle")).getText());
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
    //select date
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='rb-calendar_onward_cal']//td[.='15']")).click();
```